# Hibernate HQL Update Issue

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am getting one strange issue in Hibernate HQL update query. Below is the code I am using to update the table.

```
String update = "update SomeTable set reschEffDate=:reschEffDate,deferalFromInstl=:deferalFromInstl where loanId='"+ stageRepricing.getLoanId()+ "' and reschId='"+ stageRepricing.getReschId() + "'";
Query query = session.createQuery(update);
query.setParameter("reschEffDate",stageRepricing.getReschEffDate());
query.setParameter("deferalFromInstl", Integer.toString(stageRepricing.getDeferalFromInstl()));
```

Now the moment I add second column (`deferalFromInstl`) in query, I get below strange exception.

```
Illegal char &lt;:> at index 17: deferalFromInstl=:deferalFromInstl.class at session.createQuery(update);
```

If I remove this column, the query works fine. Let me know if anyone have faced this issue and what is the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with above update statement. Actually the problem was, that there should be space between fieldname and placeholder. Like below.

String update = "update SomeTable set reschEffDate = :reschEffDate,deferalFromInstl = :deferalFromInstl where loanId = :loanId and reschId = :reschId";

After the above changes I did not get the error and table updated successfully.